# calling a function recursively in appium node.js script

Tags: node.js, loops, callback, mocha.js, appium

I am trying to click on an element in android simulator using appium , till a particular text is visible on the screen .
For example i have to click on a calender next month icon till i receive checkText = July 2017.

The code i am using is :

```
exports.keepClickingWhileTextIsNot = function(element, checkText) {
    var nextbtn = driver.elementById('datePickerViewMonthNameTextView')
    return element.click().then(function(nextbtn){
            return nextbtn.text().then(function(text) {
            if (text == checkText) {
              driver.elementByXPath('//android.widget.TextView[@text=\'17\']').click()
            } else {
                return driver.keepClickingWhileTextIsNot(element, checkText);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

The next icon is clicking repeatedly and is as expected , but it is not stopping on July 2017. Its not coming in if block when text on the android equals July 2017. I have tried string1.equals(string2) as well.

As per logs value of the variable text is coming as NaN.
Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your comparing strings instead of integers

try converting them to integers before comparison

```
parseInt(text) == parseInt(checkText)
```

Comment: Thanks Sunder, but this doesn't work . The value of text in logs is coming as 0 for every iteration

Comment: can you please print the text for every iteration before parsing and after parsing??